# How to select rows with at least one categorical value in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

How I can retrieve indexes of the rows, in a pandas DataFrame (df), with "object" type (dtype=='O') in at least one column of the DataFrame?

What I would like to do in practice is to create a new dataframe (numeric_df) with only the numeric values of a source dataframe (df).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'object col':[1,'a',25]})
df[df['object col'].apply(lambda x: type(x))==int]
```

result:

[image]

Based on the comment:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'object col':[1,'a',25], 'object col2':['a','a',25]})
def check(row):
  for col in row:
    if type(col)==str:
      return False
  return True
df[df.apply(check, axis = 1)]
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I should check it on every column of the dataframe, not just in a specific one (i.e.: 'object col') there is a way to do this?

Comment: Provide a simple df and the desired output.

Comment: `lambda x: f(x)` is something bad for `f`

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,'a',25] , 'col2':[14,6,'y'] , 'col3':[1,44,25] })

The output should be the rows whitout any non numeric value, in this case only the first row of the dataframe df

Comment: See the answer.